# Scope Identity error in SSIS Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, scope, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE SSIS_AuditResults(
AuditID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
PackageName varchar(35),
ExecutionTime datetime,
Filename_Path varchar(100),
RecordCount integer,
EndTime datetime,
PackageStatus varchar(10)
)
```

Above is my Table. I am using the query below to execute SQL TASK

```
INSERT INTO SSIS_AuditResults(PackageName,ExecutionTime)
SELECT ? ,?
select scope_identity()
```

In parameter I am mapping packagename and executuion time.
In result mapping I am creating a new variable with name

```
Identity_Generator 
data type int 64,value 0
```

After executing my package i am getting the error below

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "Identity_Generator": "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::Identity_Generator" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

I am giving INT but it is showing me an error. Can someone help me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: The int data type in SQL Server will match the Int32 SSIS data type. It appears you have defined it as Int64 (bigint in SQL Server types). Further, how have you defined your Execute SQL Command? Resultset or no? What does your Parameter and Result Set tab look like?

Comment: I am using INT64 ..NOW I CHANGED BACK TO INT32 MY SSIS Package started working.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data types in SSIS are not allowed to change, unless it's an Object type. Your table defined `AuditID` as int. A SQL Server int data type correlates to the Int32 data type in SSIS.

Your package defined the `Identity_Generator` SSIS Variable as type Int64 which is analogous to bigint in SQL Server data types.

To resolve this, you will need to make your types align: either change your SQL Server types to bigint or change your Variable to Int32. The correct approach will depend upon the specifics of your environment.